# Devise/Warden/Rails: Server-side session store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, warden

I'm using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) in a Rails application, and I can set session data through the `user_session` hash.  But all the session data is stored in a cookie, which causes network overhead and is potentially breakage-prone when the data gets larger than 4KB.

I'd much rather like to store session data on the server side, for example in the database, memcached, or even in memory (I'm not so worried about problems with load balancing).  Before I go reinvent the wheel, is there some established way to do this?

(I know I could simply add fields to the user model, but I'd much rather like to just have a [JSON-serialized] free-form hash or so to keep it simple.)

Comment: I'm confused as to why such a widely used gem would break the standard convention of storing a record ID rather than a serialized object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for ActiveRecordStore. Here is the rails [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/CGI/Session/ActiveRecordStore).

Comment: I think for Rails 3, that's [ActiveRecord::SessionStore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SessionStore.html), right?  So how do I use this with with Devise?  Should I just pass `current_user.id` as the session_id?

Comment: no, that would defeat half the purpose of a server session store.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to implement it but conceptually you have session on the client side. This has an id and you use `session_id` to look up the session on the server which is how you get your user, or whatever

Comment: Hm, why would it defeat the purpose?  It seems to me that the user model id is a good way to identify the user and associate a server-side session?

Comment: It defeats the purpose because half the point of a server side session is to hide the user.

Comment: a session corresponds more to "person using a browser" than a user. e.g. if you are logged into two browsers simultaneously your session should be unique per browser, that's an example of why the user id isn't the best thing to key a session on. Another example would be if you're site needs to use a session before someone is logged in. What would you key it on?